# Type HalfOpenInterval<T> does not conform to protocol BooleanType

Tags: for-loop, swift, range, intervals

I have a very simple for loop that is giving me troubles. This code ran without issue in Xcode beta 4, but in beta 5 it is complaining that the half open interval (and the closed interval) don't conform to BooleanType. What has changed, why doesn't this work anymore, or is this a bug?

```
for let i = 0; i..<cellCount!; ++i {
    //do stuff
}
```

`cellCount` is defined as an optional `Int` property:

```
private var cellCount: Int?
```

I have tried storing the cellCount into a non-optional constant but the issue still remains:

```
let numberOfCells: Int = cellCount!
for let i = 0; i..<numberOfCells; ++i {
    //do stuff
}
```

I see in the Release Notes a lot has changed with Ranges, but nothing seems to be relevant to this issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ranges are meant to be used in a `for in` loop:

```
for i in 0..<cellCount! {
    // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this have anything to do with HalfOpenInterval? I thought the struct is Range?
If you use HalfOpenInterval in for-in, it will not work. It is not of protocol SequenceType

[image]